# Android: How to keep reference to Media Player?

Tags: android

I'm building an application which players sound using the Media Player class.

If I use the back button to go to the menu and then reopen the app the music is still playing but if I play another track, the app seems to create a new media player. I can't put a reference saved instance state because it isn't serializble.

What's the recommended technique for keeping the reference?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you place your MediaPlayer behind a Service.  I've found that a really good example of how to do this, as well as bind to that service and play media, is the NPR Radio app which is open source.  You can find the source [here](http://code.google.com/p/npr-android-app/)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the lifecycle diagram of Activity, and make sure you're not creating multiple MediaPlayer objects without releasing the old ones. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Are you using MediaPlayer.create()?  That allocates a new MediaPlayer object, but doesn't do anything to the old one. Call release() before calling create() a second time.

```
playSound(){
  mp.release();
  mp = MediaPlayer.create();
  mp.start();
}
```

If you're managing it manually try putting your calls in these places.

```
    onCreate(){
      mp=new MediaPlayer();
    }
    onDestroy(){
      mp.release();
      wl.release();
    }
    playSound(){
      mp.reset();
      mp.setDatasource();
      mp.prepare();
      mp.start();
    }
    stopSound(){
     mp.reset();
    }
```

To keep the sound playing

```
onCreate(){
  PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
  wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "com.pzizz");
}
playSound(){    
  wl.acquire();
}
onDestroy(){
  wl.release();
}
stopSound(){
  wl.release();
}
```

add this to your manifest for wakelock permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: What if I want the app to keep playing sound when the activity is not active, do I need to implement a service?

Comment: I updated the code to use wakelocks, which will keep the sound playing.